# obtener la suma de un atributo en sql

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo estas dos tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero obtener la suma de estados de todos los usuarios, por ejemplo

```
user1: estado=1
user1: estado=0
user2: estado=1
user1: estado=0
user1: estado=1
user1: estado=1
user2: estado=0
user2: estado=1
```

**quiero la suma, el resultado seria:**

> para el user 1: suma de estado 1= 3, suma de estado 0=2,
>
> para el user 2: suma de estado 1= 2, suma de estado 0=2

estuve intentando:

```
objBD.query('SELECT * from USUARIO ', function(err, rows, fields) {
    //debo usa un for para la consulta de abajo
        objBD.query('SELECT SUM(estado) from USUARIO u INNER JOIN INTENTO i ON u.ID_U=i.ID_U where estado=? and u.ID_U=?',[1,rows[0].ID_U], function(err, rows, fields) {
            console.log(rows);            
        });
    });
```

Mi consulta solo esta pensado para el valor de `estado=0`, deberia hacer lo mismo para `estado=1`, no creo que sea la mejor manera, quiero que me ayuden a crear una consulta mas limpia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso, no es la función `SUM` que debes usar, porque no es que quieras *sumar el valor* del campo `estado`. De hecho, esto te va a dar resultados incorrectos cuando `estado = 0`, porque la suma siempre va a resultar en 0. Mas bien, quieres usar la función `COUNT()` para *contar los registros* con el valor `estado` deseado:

```
select count(*)
  from usuario u
  join intento i
    on i.id_u = u.id_u
   and i.estado = ?
 where u.id_u = ?
```

**Edición**

Si deseas obtener las cuentas de cada estado para un usuario en particular, puedes hacerlo usando la función `COUNT()` con una expresión `CASE`:

```
select count(case when i.estado = 0 then 'X' end) as cnt_estado_0,
       count(case when i.estado = 1 then 'X' end) as cnt_estado_1
  from usuario u
  join intento i
    on i.id_u = u.id_u
 where u.id_u = ?
```

Y, si el deseo es de obtener estas cuentas para todos los usuarios de un solo, puedes modificar la consulta de esta manera (nota que aquí el `LEFT JOIN` es necesario si es posible que un usuario no tenga registros en la tabla `intento`):

```
select u.id_u,
       count(case when i.estado = 0 then 'X' end) as cnt_estado_0,
       count(case when i.estado = 1 then 'X' end) as cnt_estado_1
  from usuario u
  left join intento i
    on i.id_u = u.id_u
 group by u.id_u
```

Comment: pero para que funcione para los 2 valores, 0 y 1 deberia repetir 2 veces la misma consulta?

Comment: ¿No es eso lo que quieres? Si no es eso, ¿cual es el resultado que buscas en realidad? ¿Para un usuario en particular, deseas los counts para cada estado?

Comment: asi es para cada estado, sus respectivos counts

Comment: ¿Cuantos estados  son posibles? ¿Solo 0 y 1?

Comment: si solo dos estados

Comment: Agregué una edición a la respuesta.

Comment: funcionan al 100, problema resuelto

Comment: lo pase a mysql y funciona bien el segundo ejemplo, pero desde nodejs sale error de syntaxis

Comment: Seguramente por las comillas simples en la consulta. No soy conocedor de nodejs, pero seguramente hay una manera de "escapar" las comillas, ¿no?

Comment: O mejor aun, creo que puedes usar comillas dobles para pasar la consulta, ¿no?  Algo como: `objBD.query("SELECT ... ", ...`

Comment: tu ultimo comentario fue el acertado!!!